# Git tags for release versions with divergent master and release branches

Tags: git, version-control, merge, branch

Let's say we're using the following branch strategy in git:

- The `master` branch for continuous development of new features.
- A `release` branch which gets created at some point prior to an upcoming release to stabilize.

Once the `release` branch is created, some developers continue to commit to `master` (working on features for later releases) while other developers work to finalize the current release. During the existence of the `release` branch, commits from `master` are **not** merged in to preserve the release branch's stability.

At release time, the final commit in the `release` branch is tagged with the release version. Then, a merge is performed from `release` into `master` (obviously not fast-forward, due to concurrent development on both branches).

Now imagine later down the road (after more commits to `master`), we want to reset the repository back to the state of the last release.

**Wouldn't rolling back to the tagged release commit in `master` result in a different repository state than what we had on the `release` branch?** (Unless I'm missing something, this would be the case since the commits to `master` during the time when both branches were under active development have remained in the commit history even after rolling back `master` since they occurred before the tagged release commit.)

Rebasing instead of merging the `release` branch back in to `master` would solve this problem it seems, but that's not a viable option with multiple developers working on `master`.

Any thoughts?

***EDIT: Thanks to @jthill's answer, adding diagrams to explain the situation and why I was confused.***

Here is a diagram of what has actually happened:

```
...o---X---o---o---o---M  master
         \             /
          a---b---c---R    release
                      ^
                    (v1.0, final commit in release branch)
```

Now, here is a diagram of what the linear commit history looks like from `master` (which was driving my mistaken mental model) -- note that the `o` refs and the `a`/`b`/`c` refs have intermingled based on their commit timestamps. This is what was throwing me off -- the flat commit history does not make it clear that if you rollback to ref `R`, all of the `o` commits following `X` will also be removed!

```
...o---X---o---a---b---o---c---o---R---M  master
                                   ^
                                 (v1.0, final commit in release branch)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your text description,

> - the final commit in the release branch is tagged
> - Then, a merge is performed from release into master

from which I get this picture:

```
 ...o---X---o---o---o...M  master
         \             /
          o---o---o...R    release
                      ^
                    (v1.0, final commit in release branch)
```

You've only named three refs here, the ones shown in this picture.  Notice that

> Wouldn't rolling back to *the tagged release commit in master*

doesn't square up with the tag-then-merge sequence you described, but whether `v1.0` refers to `R` or `M`, the only ref you mention changing since `M` is `master`.

To answer your question:

> Wouldn't rolling back to the tagged release commit in master result in a different repository state than what we had on the release branch?

`git checkout -B master M` will leave those three refs exactly where they are in that picture, so, no.

---

Now: suppose I've misunderstood you somehow.  Think: no matter what my misunderstanding, to correct me you'll have to tell me which refs were on which commits — so if you put them back there now, you'll have your desire.

Comment: Got it. Your picture is correct; my mental model was wrong. I was thinking that after merging `release` back to `master`, the 3 refs behind `R` on the release branch would be embedded wherever they fit in time between the commits from `X` to `M`. But in reality, the changes in each of those is committed in the new merge commit `M`. The final question is, will those refs remain accessible (including the tag to `R`) even if the `release` branch is deleted?

Comment: Refs move only when you tell git to move them.  Everything else is immutable, stuff that's completely unreachable from any known reference will get gc'd eventually (see [the config docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) for the gc settings) and e.g. [the prune docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-prune.html) for skinny on what's going on

Comment: Another way to put it then: if I view the commit history for `master` after the merge, I won't see ref `R` in it (with my version tag) correct? I would have to specifically checkout that tag instead?

Comment: Wherever your ref is, `git log` will show you everything reachable from it by default.  If you don't want master at the merge, reset it to `M~`, M's mainline parent.

Comment: I edited my question to add a diagram of what I was thinking (and seeing) when sitting on the `master` branch after the merge.